# MDX queries test

Tags: mdx, mondrian

I want to combine 3 queries like that in one query but I don't know how can I do this:

Query 1:

```
select {
Crossjoin({[Measures].[Store sales]}, {[Occupation].[Occupation].Members}) 
} on columns,
{
[Product].[Product Family].Members
} on rows
From test
```

Comment: Query 1 & 2 are identical.Please edit one with the actual query

Answer (score 0):

Something like this is ok - but you need to bring All members into the script so that each set of tuples has the same dimensionality:

```
SELECT 
    [Measures].[Store sales]
  * 
    {
      [Occupation].[Occupation].MEMBERS * {[Essai].[All]}
     ,
      {[Occupation].[All]} * [Essai].[Essai].MEMBERS
    } ON COLUMNS
 ,{[Product].[Product Family].MEMBERS} ON ROWS
FROM test;
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, the second query is

```
select {
Crossjoin({[Measures].[Store sales]}, {[Yearly_Income].   [Yearly_Income].Members}) 
} on columns,
{
[Product].[Product Family].Members
} on rows
From test
```

Comment: you can still use the idea i posted - aslong as the All members are include to keep dimensionality the same then it should work